# IBOutlets not showing up in storyboard for iPad Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm creating some outlets for my UI scroll views.

These outlets show up just fine in the iPhone Interface Builder but in the iPad interface builder they are nowhere to be seen.

Any idea why?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollerLong;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollerHuge;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollerMassive;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *mediumScroll;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollerHome;
}
```

Comment: Did you change your iPad view controller type to ViewController?

Comment: I put the new ViewController types into the Interface Builder screen the same as I did with the iPhone where do you check what type a view is?

Comment: It is in Identity Inspector panel, I think it is always on the right pane of Interface Builder. You should change class at Custom class section to ViewController

Comment: That's wierd I checked and it was iPad view controllers are set to "UIViewController" by default, looking at the code above it looks like it would work but it actually doesn't.  I was able to change the Classname to ViewController in the iPad and now it's working like i'd expect, thanks for your help I got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property in the header file:

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```